# Django admin filter on edit page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

On a Django admin edit page, I would like to add a little search box to be able to filter a list of tags. The field tag is a many to many field.

[image]
Is there a special trick?

Comment: You can try this, [django-simple-select2](https://github.com/jerinpetergeorge/django-simple-select2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the documentation on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

The code below adds a search box:

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']


class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['tags']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't add search field inside the box but you can search for the same field value at the top
add this to your admin.py file

```
#admin.py 



from django.contrib import admin
from Your_app.models import Your_model
    
class example_class(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['ManyToManyFiledname']
    
 

admin.site.register(Your_model,example_class)
```